# mongoose match values and update query

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have an array like

```
const names = ["mike","alice","jesse"];
```

i have document

```
{

"name":"alice", // could be any name
"age":17,
"occupation":"engineer",

}
```

now I want to match names from array and if they match then I update the document. I have quite long array and more than 500 documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may  try this if names array is to big.

`if(names. indexof(incoming_name) > -1){
//update query with where name:incoming_name
}`

Comment: can you give me query to find the match and update!

Comment: `const result = await modelname.findOneAndUpdate(
   { "name" : incoming_name },
   { $set: { "age" : age, "occupation" : occupation, }, {new:true} }
);`